# getting Invalid Email or Password in my localhost website

Tags: php, passwords, localhost

i'm using php 7.2.31 .. i'v already imported my DB file in phpmyAdmin

when i'm trying to login in admin website page (or the others 2 users ) it's getting this message  :-

(Invalid Email or Password )

the email address and password already in the database and it's correct  .. ! !

here's my login-in code :-

```
<?php session_start();?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup_style.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
<title>Admin Panel</title>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="description" content="#">
<meta name="keywords" content="Admin , Responsive">
<meta name="author" content="Nikhil Bhalerao +919423979339.">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/assets/icon/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/assets/icon/icofont/css/icofont.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="fix-menu">

<?php
  include('connect.php');
  extract($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['btn_login']))
{
  $passw = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
  function createSalt()
  {
      return '2123293dsj2hu2nikhiljdsd';
  }
  $salt = createSalt();
  $pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $passw);
//echo $pass;
  if($_POST['user'] == 'admin'){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE loginid='" .$email . "' and password = '". $pass."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //print_r($row);    
    $_SESSION["adminid"] = $row['id'];
     $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
     $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];
     $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];
     $_SESSION["email"] = $row['loginid'];
     $_SESSION["fname"] = $row['fname'];
     $_SESSION["lname"] = $row['lname'];
     $_SESSION['image'] = $row['image'];
     $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  }else if($_POST['user'] == 'doctor'){    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE loginid='" .$email . "' and password = '". $pass."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //print_r($row);    

    $_SESSION["doctorid"] = $row['doctorid'];
     $_SESSION["id"] = $row['doctorid'];
     $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];
     $_SESSION["email"] = $row['loginid'];
     $_SESSION["fname"] = $row['doctorname'];
     $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  }else if($_POST['user'] == 'patient'){    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE loginid='" .$email . "' and password = '". $pass."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //print_r($row);    
    $_SESSION["patientid"] = $row['patientid'];
     $_SESSION["id"] = $row['patientid'];
     $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];
     $_SESSION["email"] = $row['loginid'];
     $_SESSION["fname"] = $row['patientname'];
     $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  }
    //print_r($row);
     $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if($count==1 && isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    {       
        ?>
         <div class="popup popup--icon -success js_success-popup popup--visible">
          <div class="popup__background"></div>
          <div class="popup__content">
            <h3 class="popup__content__title">
              Success 
            </h3>
            <p>Login Successfully</p>
            <p>
             <!--  <a href="index.php"><button class="button button--success" data-for="js_success-popup"></button></a> -->
             <?php echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'index.php';\",1500);</script>"; ?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
   <!--   <script>
     window.location="index.php";
     </script> -->
     <?php
    }
}
else {?>
     <div class="popup popup--icon -error js_error-popup popup--visible">
      <div class="popup__background"></div>
      <div class="popup__content">
        <h3 class="popup__content__title">
          Error 
        </h3>
        <p>Invalid Email or Password</p>
        <p>
          <a href="login.php"><button class="button button--error" data-for="js_error-popup">Close</button></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
      }

   }
?>


<?php
$que="select * from manage_website";
$query=$conn->query($que);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  //print_r($row);
  extract($row);
  $business_name = $row['business_name'];
  $business_email = $row['business_email'];
  $business_web = $row['business_web'];
  $portal_addr = $row['portal_addr'];
  $addr = $row['addr'];
  $curr_sym = $row['curr_sym'];
  $curr_position = $row['curr_position'];
  $front_end_en = $row['front_end_en'];
  $date_format = $row['date_format'];
  $def_tax = $row['def_tax'];
  $logo = $row['logo'];
}
?>


<section class="login-block">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">



<div class="auth-box card" >
  <div class="text-center">
<image class="profile-img" src="uploadImage/Logo/<?php echo $logo; ?>" style="width: 60%"></image>
</div> 
<div class="card-block" >

<div class="row m-b-20">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h5 class="text-center txt-primary">Sign In</h5>
</div>
</div>
  <form method="POST" >
    <div class="form-group form-primary">
      <select name="user" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
        <option value="patient">Patient</option>
      </select>
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-primary">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-primary">
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Password">
      <span class="form-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-25 text-left">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="forgot-phone text-right f-right">
          <a href="forgot_password.php" class="text-right f-w-600"> Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-30">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" name="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block waves-effect text-center m-b-20">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>


</div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/jquery/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/popper.js/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/modernizr/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/modernizr/js/css-scrollbars.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/i18next/js/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/i18next-xhr-backend/js/i18nextXHRBackend.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/i18next-browser-languagedetector/js/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bower_components/jquery-i18next/js/jquery-i18next.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/assets/js/common-pages.js"></script>


</body>

<!-- for any PHP, Codeignitor or Laravel work contact me at mayuri.infospace@gmail.com -->
</html>
```

and the check-login file :-

```
<?php 
session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"]))){
    $myemail = $_SESSION['email'];
}else {
    header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

thanks !

Comment: Firstly - don't store plain text passwords in the database, have a read of how to use [`password_hash()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Just as important is [not to store the password in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594202/is-it-secure-to-store-a-password-in-a-session).

Comment: You should echo down the sql, what it is getting. Then compare the data with database data.

Comment: Nigel Ren .. thanks i'll edit it

Comment: Razin .. how's that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 
**invalid Email and password** because the variable $email which you are using in your query has no email from the form. After this line:

```
$pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $passw);
```

Add this line:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

This will solve your problem. But there are many other other problems in your code like it is open to SQL injection. You can use prepare statements.
[PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Always validate the data coming from users.

Do not store password as a plain text. See here [password-encryption-storing-password-in-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293815/password-encryption-storing-password-in-session)

If you want to get only one record from a database always use **LIMIT 1** in your code.

Comment: thanks for your advice for the password store way ...
i already added the line ...same problem ...  invalid Email and password

Comment: That's because you curly braces {} of if conditions are not well place. You are using two opening braces {{ for the if condition where you are checking for count == 1. Moreover this if condition should be outside of if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])) condition.

Comment: Try to write your code clean. Also the createSalt() function can be declared outside the condition